# Fastest way to iterate through nodes with arbitrary number of connections to each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a fracturing script where there are nodes that each hold an arbitrary number of connections to other nodes.

Shards and chunks :

[image: Shards and chunks]

Each node represents a "shard" of a pre-fractured "chunk".

When a shard is broken all its connections to other shards and their connections to it are removed.

When this happens, I need to iterate through the shards and find out which are connected together and if the chunk is split apart to create new chunks.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Currently I have:

- a Shard class that has

  - a reference to the parent chunk
  - a list of connections to adjacent shards.
  - a Break() method that

    - removes all connections from adjacent shards to this one.
    - clears the connections from this to adjacent shards.
    - calls the parent chunk's UpdateChunk() method.
- a Chunk class that has

  - a list of all the shards that it contains.
  - an UpdateChunk() method that

    - checks if there is only one shard and then destroys this chunk.
    - makes a new list of all the shards in this chunk to keep track of 
      unprocessed shards.
    - calls ProcessShard() method to recursively process all shards 
      through their connections starting form the first shard in the 
      unprocessed shard list.
    - checks if there are still shards in the unprocessed list and if so 
      creates a new chunk and dumps the leftover shards in it and calls 
      its UpdateChunk() method.
  - a ProcessShard() method that

    - removes given shard from the unprocessed list
    - makes given shard's parent chunk the current chunk
    - loops through all the shards this one connects to and checks if they 
      are not in the processed list and if so calls ProcessShard() for 
      them.

```cs
public class Shard : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject parentChunk;

    public List<GameObject> connectedShards = new List<GameObject>();

    public void Break()
    {
        // remove all connections that point to this shard
        foreach (GameObject shard in connectedShards)
        {
            // remove connection to this shard
            shard.GetComponent<Shard>().connectedShards.Remove(gameObject);
        }

        // clear connected shards list
        connectedShards.Clear();

        // check that there is a parent chunk
        if (parentChunk)
        {
            // force parent chunk to update
            parentChunk.GetComponent<Chunk>().UpdateChunk();

            // set parent chunk to null
            parentChunk = null;
        }
    }
}




public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> shards = new List<GameObject>();

    private List<GameObject> unprocessedShards = new List<GameObject>();

    public void UpdateChunk()
    {
        // if there is only one shard in this chunk
        if (shards.Count == 1)
        {
            // break shard
            shards[0].GetComponent<Shard>().parentChunk = null;
            shards[0].GetComponent<Shard>().Break();

            // destroy this chunk
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else // there are multiple shards in this chunk
        {
            // fill the unprocessed shards list
            unprocessedShards = new List<GameObject>(shards);

            // process all shards in this chunk recursively starting from the first
            ProcessShard(unprocessedShards[0], gameObject);

            // if there are still unprocessed shards (this chunk was split)
            if (unprocessedShards.Count > 0)
            {
                // remove the unprocessed shards from this chunk's shard list
                foreach (GameObject unprocessedShard in unprocessedShards)
                {
                    shards.Remove(unprocessedShard);
                }

                // create new chunk(s) from the leftover shards
                parentObject.GetComponent<Fragmenter>().NewChunk(unprocessedShards);
            }
        }
    }



    // process shard
    private void ProcessShard(GameObject shard, GameObject chunk)
    {
        // remove shard from unprocessed list
        unprocessedShards.Remove(shard);

        // add shard to the given chunk
        shard.GetComponent<Shard>().parentChunk = chunk;

        // loop through all shards connected to the given shard
        foreach (GameObject connectedShard in shard.GetComponent<Shard>().connectedShards)
        {
            // connected shard has not been processed yet
            if (unprocessedShards.Contains(connectedShard))
            {
                // process all shards connected to the connected shard
                ProcessShard(connectedShard, chunk);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am mostly thinking about the ProcessShard() method where it usually processes each shard multiple times since one can be adjacent to many. How can I most efficiently ignore the ones that have already been processed?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would suggest moving away from `List.Remove` since worst case it needs to check each item to find the one to remove. Instead of removing shards that are being processed from the list of unprocessed shards, you could keep another list of processed shards and add to that. Then your condition checking if the connected shard is unprocessed would become `if(!processedShards.Contains(connectedShard))`.

You can read more about the performance of List operations on the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.8), just scroll down to the Remarks section.

---

Another improvement would be to find an alternative to `List.Contains` when checking if a shard has been processed. Similarly to `List.Remove`, it needs to potentially check each item in the list before it can tell if the item is present.

One way to do so would be to use a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) instead of a List. It provides much quicker ways to access specific items and to check if items are present in the collection. It also provides many of the same methods so refactoring should be a breeze.

---

Just as a note, personally I wouldn't bother with optimization until performance becomes an issue. You might find these improvements gain you next to nothing as your collections just aren't large enough. If you have not yet, check out the [Unity profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) and from there gauge where your big performance hits are coming from.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I didn't even know about HashSet. Unfortunately, as you noted, it didn't affect the speed at these collection sizes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the script slowed down the most at the recursion of the ProcessShard() method so I renamed and rewrote the method as ProcessShards() that uses a while loop and a Queue to process all the shards. The performance was around ten times better on a chunk with 100 shards.

```
    // process shards
    private void ProcessShards()
    {
        // create a list for shards to process
        Queue<GameObject> shardsToProcess = new Queue<GameObject>();

        // select the first shard to process
        shardsToProcess.Enqueue(unprocessedShards[0]);

        // remove shard from unprocessed list
        unprocessedShards.Remove(unprocessedShards[0]);

        // loop while there are shards to process
        while (shardsToProcess.Count > 0)
        {
            // get the first shard to process
            GameObject shard = shardsToProcess.Dequeue();

            // add the shard to this chunk
            shard.GetComponent<Shard>().parentChunk = gameObject;

            // loop through all shards connected to the given shard
            foreach (GameObject connectedShard in shard.GetComponent<Shard>().connectedShards)
            {
                // connected shard has not been processed yet
                if (unprocessedShards.Contains(connectedShard))
                {
                    // add shard to be processed
                    shardsToProcess.Enqueue(connectedShard);

                    // remove shard from unprocessed list
                    unprocessedShards.Remove(connectedShard);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```